# Receiving txt messages on two apple devices

Tags: iphone, ipad, icloud

When ever I send or receive a text message from my iPhone, it appears on my spouses iPad and iPhone. Yet, the reverse is not true. I think this is an iCloud issue and my be controlled by adjusting preferences somewhere, but I don't know how.

Comment: Ask your spouse to remove the sync to your accounts from his device :)

Answer (score 2):

Are you sharing one iCloud account? You can set separate apple accounts for iCloud and applications. My spouse and I use the same account to purchase apps (so that we don't have to buy apps twice to each have a copy), the same account for music (so that if I buy a song, she gets it too), but separate iCloud accounts to make sure we each only receive messages intended for us. Check your settings and see. AppleIDs are free, if you are not using your own for your devices iCloud, you ought to do so.